# fetch values of the array that has a sub array json values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have this JSON response/

```
{  
   "phweb":{  
      "name":"PH Web Server",
      "cpu":"36.7",
      "ram":"33.0",
      "hdd":"43.0",
      "os":{  
         "osup":"2 days, 23 hours, 5 minutes and 34 seconds",
         "osstat":"0"
      },
      "apache":{  
         "apachestat":"0",
         "apacheup":"33 days, 2 hours, 9 minutes and 16 seconds"
      },
      "sql":{  
         "sqlstat":"0",
         "sqlup":"154 days, 2 hours, 16 minutes and 53 seconds"
      }
   },
   "phdbm":{  
      "name":"PH DBM Server",
      "cpu":"15.9",
      "ram":"10.7",
      "hdd":"23.7",
      "os":{  
         "osup":"2 days, 23 hours, 6 minutes and 21 seconds",
         "osstat":"0"
      },
      "apache":{  
         "apachestat":"0",
         "apacheup":"103 days, 4 hours, 43 minutes and 56 seconds"
      },
      "sql":{  
         "sqlstat":"0",
         "sqlup":"12 days, 4 hours, 43 minutes and 42 seconds"
      }
   }
}
```

and I could fetch each value using

```
$.each(response, function(index, value){
    console.log(index + " " + value);
});
```

How can I fetch the value of a response value that has a sub array values e.g.

```
      "os":{  
         "osup":"2 days, 23 hours, 6 minutes and 21 seconds",
         "osstat":"0"
      },
```

of the "phweb" index (assume i want to get the 'osup' from 'os' of 'phweb'? and how can I check if its empty or it did exist (to avoid errors)?

Comment: There's no arrays here, just objects. Therefore you can use `response.phweb.os` to access the nested object. It will be `undefined` if there was no matching property

Answer (score 1):

First it is JSON `object` not JSON `array`.

You can directly access it using `key`.

Use variable name e.g `obj` and use `.` operator with key to value of that key.

In below example it is `obj.phweb.os` which means obj is JSON object having multiple key value pair including key `phweb` and same for `phweb` and `os`.

**Keep In Mind**: JSON object has `key value` and wrap in `{}` while array has index and wrap in `[]`.

```js
var obj = {  
   "phweb":{  
      "name":"PH Web Server",
      "cpu":"36.7",
      "ram":"33.0",
      "hdd":"43.0",
      "os":{  
         "osup":"2 days, 23 hours, 5 minutes and 34 seconds",
         "osstat":"0"
      },
      "apache":{  
         "apachestat":"0",
         "apacheup":"33 days, 2 hours, 9 minutes and 16 seconds"
      },
      "sql":{  
         "sqlstat":"0",
         "sqlup":"154 days, 2 hours, 16 minutes and 53 seconds"
      }
   },
   "phdbm":{  
      "name":"PH DBM Server",
      "cpu":"15.9",
      "ram":"10.7",
      "hdd":"23.7",
      "os":{  
         "osup":"2 days, 23 hours, 6 minutes and 21 seconds",
         "osstat":"0"
      },
      "apache":{  
         "apachestat":"0",
         "apacheup":"103 days, 4 hours, 43 minutes and 56 seconds"
      },
      "sql":{  
         "sqlstat":"0",
         "sqlup":"12 days, 4 hours, 43 minutes and 42 seconds"
      }
   }
}

console.log(obj.phweb.os);
```